# cudaDeviceSynchronize() waits to finish only in current CUDA context or in all contexts?

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I use **CUDA 6.5** and **4 x GPUs Kepler**.

I use multithreading, CUDA runtime API and access to the CUDA contexts from different CPU threads (by using OpenMP - but it does not really matter).

1. When I call `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` will it wait for kernel(s) to finish only in current CUDA context which selected by the latest call `cudaSetDevice()`, or in all CUDA contexts?
2. If it will wait for kernel(s) to finish in all CUDA contexts, then it will wait in all CUDA contexts which used in current CPU thread (*in example CPU thread_0 will wait GPUs: 0 and 1*) or generally all CUDA contexts (*CPU thread_0 will wait GPUs: 0, 1, 2 and 3*)?

Following code:

```
// For using OpenMP requires to set:
// MSVS option: -Xcompiler "/openmp"
// GCC option: –Xcompiler –fopenmp
#include <omp.h>

int main() {

    // execute two threads with different: omp_get_thread_num() = 0 and 1
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        int omp_threadId = omp_get_thread_num();

        // CPU thread 0
        if(omp_threadId == 0) {

            cudaSetDevice(0);
            kernel_0<<<...>>>(...);
            cudaSetDevice(1);
            kernel_1<<<...>>>(...);

            cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // what kernel<>() will wait?

        // CPU thread 1
        } else if(omp_threadId == 1) {

            cudaSetDevice(2);
            kernel_2<<<...>>>(...);
            cudaSetDevice(3);
            kernel_3<<<...>>>(...);

            cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // what kernel<>() will wait?

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> When I call cudaDeviceSynchronize(); will it wait for kernel(s) to
>   finish only in current CUDA context which selected by the latest call
>   cudaSetDevice(), or in all CUDA contexts?

`cudaDeviceSynchronize()` syncs all streams in the **current CUDA context only**.

---

Note: `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` will only synchronize host with the currently set GPU, if multiple GPUs are in use and all need to be synchronized, `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` has to be called separately for each one.

Here is a minimal example:

```
cudaSetDevice(0); cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaSetDevice(1); cudaDeviceSynchronize();
...
```

**Source**: Pawel Pomorski, slides of "CUDA on multiple GPUs". Linked [here](http://ppomorsk.sharcnet.ca/CSE746/lecture9_CSE746_2014.pdf).

Comment: In the case of 1 GPU and multiple CPU threads, if I call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` from one CPU thread, will it wait for other CPU threads to finish their work on the device?